# Python IDLE won't work on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have a Mac OS X 10.6.8, and my IDLE doesn't work. The error message the console is giving is:

```
_tkinter.Tclerror bad event type or keysym "enter"
```

After doing some reading in forums, etc., I understand that the problem was because of new preferences I tried to apply on it with the wrong syntax.

So I tried to uninstall Python and delete all the files related to it and then reinstall it again, but the Idle still doesn't run and still gives me the same error message. I am clueless about what else can I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say this happened after setting preferences, and the problem persists when you uninstall and reinstall IDLE, then the problem probably isn't with IDLE, but with your preferences. The preferences probably aren't deleted when you uninstall IDLE.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629655/7432), IDLE saves preferences in a directory named ${HOME}/.idlerc. Delete that folder or temporarily rename it and then restart IDLE to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked! 
Though it took me a while to find out that this file was hidden, so I had to look for it using the terminal and the command: 
    ls -a