# python IDLE changing default open file location to u C:\Users\user\documents

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I open python's IDLE and want to open a .py file, the default directory location is: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32` but this is annoying because I want the default location to be in `C:\Users\user\documents`. So, how can i change the settings so that every time i try opening a file in IDLE it chooses the documents location?

Comment: You could use the command line to launch IDLE from `C:\Users\user\documents`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default working directory for Python IDLE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367688/default-working-directory-for-python-idle)

Comment: See also: [How to save custom preferences of python's IDLE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628859/how-to-save-custom-preferences-of-pythons-idle)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cmd to open py idle.

for example! - use instruction to set path to your idle:

`> set example=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonIDLE.exe`

*{set} [path_name]=[idle_execute_path]*

next, to open program use console:

`> example program.py`

*{path_name} {yourprogram.py} {args}*

Otherhand:

`import os
os.getcwd() '/home/ss'
os.chdir("codss")    #change current working directory
os.getcwd() '/home/ss/codss'`

some else to think:
may be edit file from:

> C:\Users\alfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib
>
> idle.py or pathbrowser.py

Idk, you can see here:
[Default working directory for Python IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367688/default-working-directory-for-python-idle)
or
[Default save path for Python IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424398/default-save-path-for-python-idle/)